# Cannot run program "~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I installed android studio on Ubuntu and tried running an application.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as there are problem with permission, check if you have permission to execute '.../platform-tools/adb'

Answer (score 0):

Install adb using the following comands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```